# Backtesting problem with Pandas and vectorization

Tags: python, pandas, trading, back-testing

I have this DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"val": [1, 2, 3, 5], "signal": [0, 1, 0, 0]})
df
    val signal
0   1   0
1   2   1
2   3   0
3   5   0
```

Then I do:

```py
df["target"] = np.where(df.signal, df.val + 3, np.nan)
df["target"] = df.target.ffill()
df["hit"] = df.val >= df.target
df
    val signal  target  hit
0   1   0       NaN     False
1   2   1       5.0     False
2   3   0       5.0     False
3   5   0       5.0     True
```

To see if my target has been hit.

Here's my issue: let's say that the starting DataFrame was this:

```py
    val signal
0   1   0
1   2   1
2   3   0
3   5   1 # <-- new signal
4   6   0 # <-- new row
```

If I do the same operations as before I get:

```py
df["target"] = np.where(df.signal, df.val + 3, np.nan)
df["target"] = df.target.ffill()
df["hit"] = df.val >= df.target
df
    val signal  target  hit
0   1   0       NaN     False
1   2   1       5.0     False
2   3   0       5.0     False
3   5   1       7.0     False
4   6   0       7.0     False
```

Now I lost the hit on index 3, as `target` has been replaced by the second signal.

What I would like is for `signal` to **not** create a new `target` *if the previous target has not been hit yet.*

Desired output (example 1):

```py
    val signal  target  hit
0   1   0       NaN     False
1   2   1       5.0     False
2   3   0       5.0     False
3   5   1       5.0     True
4   6   0       NaN     False
```

Desired output (example 2):

```py
    val signal  target  hit
0   1   0       NaN     False
1   2   1       5.0     False
2   3   1       5.0     False
3   5   0       5.0     True
4   6   0       NaN     False
```

Desired output (example 3):

```py
    val signal  target  hit
0   1   1       4.0     False
1   4   0       4.0     True
2   3   0       NaN     False
3   4   1       7.0     False
4   7   0       7.0     True
```

Desired output (example 4):

```py
    val signal  target  hit
0   5   0       NaN     False
1   3   1       6.0     False
2   6   1       6.0     True
3   2   1       5.0     False
4   7   0       5.0     True
```

P.S. Ideally, this needs to be done with vectorization as I'm going to perform this operation for millions of rows.

EDIT: Just so the logic is clearer, here's the "loopy" version of the algorithm:

```py
def loopy_way(vals: list, signals: list) -> list:
    active_trgt = None
    hits = []
    for val, signal in zip(vals, signals):

        if active_trgt:
            if val >= active_trgt: # Arbitrary logic
                hits.append(True)
                active_trgt = None
                continue

            # There's an active target, so ignore signal
            hits.append(False)
            continue

        if signal:
            active_trgt = val + 3 # Arbitrary condition
            hits.append(False) # Couldn't be otherwise
            continue

        # No signal and no active target
        hits.append(False)
    return hits
```

Comment: Added an answer below that maps your input and output correctly, but maybe doesn't cover all the cases you have in mind. If not, could you provide other example data that gets at what you want?

Comment: In your desired example 4, why is the 2nd target 4.0 and not 5.0?

Comment: My bad, sorry, i'm gonna edit it rn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at both the new target and the previous target at each signal point using the [`.shift` method in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html).

Tracking both will allow you to signal if either we are over the current or the previous target.

Additionally, you want to track what the largest historical value you have seen in the previous signal window. You can enumerate signal windows with `df.signal.cumsum()` and then group by that window enumeration to get the cummax just per signal window with `df.groupby(df.signal_window).val.cummax().shift(1)`.

As an additional condition for non-monotonic data, you can accept the candidate target in signal rows if it is less than the previous target.

Combining these, you can get your desired output.

I calculate and store these as intermediate columns below to show
how the logic works, but you don't have to store and then drop them in your code.

**Note:** All of this said, it may not be worth vectorizing this calculation. Using [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) or similar you could get a very fast implementation in a loop with more readable/maintainable code and substantial runtime memory savings since you don't have to do all your intermediate calculations for every row at once.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "val": [1, 2, 3, 5, 6], "signal": [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "val": [1, 2, 3, 5, 6], "signal": [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    "val": [1, 4, 3, 4, 7], "signal": [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
})

df4 = pd.DataFrame({
    "val": [5, 3, 6, 2, 7], "signal": [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
})

for df in [df1, df2, df3, df4]:
    # add candidate target at signal times
    df["candidate_target"] = np.where(df.signal, df.val + 3, np.nan)
    
    # track previous target at signal times
    df["prev_target"] = np.where(
        df.signal,
        df.candidate_target.ffill().shift(1),
        np.nan
    )
    
    # enumerate the signal windows with cumsum
    df["signal_window"] = df.signal.cumsum()
    
    # track max value we have seen in previous signal window
    df["max_to_date"] = df.groupby(df.signal_window).val.cummax().shift(1)
    
    # for signal rows, actual target is candidate if previous has been exceeded, else previous
    df["signal_target"] = np.where(
        (df.max_to_date >= df.prev_target) | df.prev_target.isnull() | (df.prev_target > df.candidate_target),
        df.candidate_target,
        df.prev_target
    )
    
    # for non-signal rows, add target only if it has not been hit
    df["non_signal_target"] = np.where(
        (df.signal == 0) & (df.max_to_date < df.signal_target.ffill()),
        df.signal_target.ffill(),
        np.nan,
    )
    
    # combine signal target and non-signal target rows
    df["target"] = df.signal_target.fillna(df.non_signal_target)
    
    # hit is where value exceeds or equal to target
    df["hit"] = df.val >= df.target
    
    # drop intermediate calculations
    df.drop(["max_to_date", "signal_target", "signal_window", "non_signal_target", "candidate_target", "prev_target"], axis=1, inplace=True)
    
    print(df)
#> val  signal  target    hit
#> 0    1       0     NaN  False
#> 1    2       1     5.0  False
#> 2    3       0     5.0  False
#> 3    5       1     5.0   True
#> 4    6       0     NaN  False
#>    val  signal  target    hit
#> 0    1       0     NaN  False
#> 1    2       1     5.0  False
#> 2    3       1     5.0  False
#> 3    5       0     5.0   True
#> 4    6       0     NaN  False
#>    val  signal  target    hit
#> 0    1       1     4.0  False
#> 1    4       0     4.0   True
#> 2    3       0     NaN  False
#> 3    4       1     7.0  False
#> 4    7       0     7.0   True
#>    val  signal  target    hit
#> 0    5       0     NaN  False
#> 1    3       1     6.0  False
#> 2    6       1     6.0   True
#> 3    2       1     5.0  False
#> 4    7       0     5.0   True
```

Comment: Edited to reflect your new examples.

Comment: this looks **really** promising. I'm going to take a more thorough look at your logic tomorrow but thank you for your effort in the meanwhile!

Comment: I tested your code and it is almost perfect. The only hiccup is this: you use `max_val` as a way to check if the new target is safe to "adopt" or if you should use the previous target. Let's say that the `val` column is not monotonically increasing. Could you make it so that `max_val` is only referencing the rows between the *last* target and the current row?

Comment: I added a 4th example showcasing an example where that would be necessary

Comment: Updated to handle that case, and to also include a note that the vectorization effort may not be worth the squeeze

Comment: Thank you @hume for taking the time to work on this problem. Your solution works so I'm going to award the correct mark to you, but the real help here was introducing me to *numba*, which I wasn't familiar with. Thank you and thanks to everyone who took time to work on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difficulty here comes from the fact that the triggers are all in one column.

To make things easier, it's always best to organize all the data needed for a conditional test into one row.

To do this here we have to think about what value we need to test for a hit for each signal.

Here I calculated the 'minimum future value below the current row'.  I did this by running the `min` function as an accumulator from the end to the beginning of the `df.val` column.

```
# Example data 1
df = pd.DataFrame({"val": [1, 2, 3, 5, 6], "signal": [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]})

from itertools import accumulate

# Calculate minimum future values
df['mf_val'] = np.fromiter(accumulate(df.val.values[::-1], min), dtype=int)[::-1]

df['hit'] = (df['val'] + 3 >= df['mf_val']).where(df.signal.astype(bool), False)

print(df)
```

Output in example 1:

```
   val  signal  mf_val    hit
0    1       0       1  False
1    2       1       2   True
2    3       0       3  False
3    5       0       5  False
4    6       0       6  False
```

Output in example 2:

```
   val  signal  mf_val    hit
0    1       0       1  False
1    2       1       2   True
2    3       1       3   True
3    5       0       5  False
4    6       0       6  False
```

Output in example 3:

```
   val  signal  mf_val    hit
0    1       1       1   True
1    4       0       3  False
2    3       0       3  False
3    4       1       4   True
4    7       0       7  False
```

This is not exactly the same as your desired values because it shows all hits and the hits are indicated in the same row as the corresponding signal.  But at least it doesn't 'erase' the first hit.  If you only want the first hit, use `df.hit.tolist().index(True)`.

**UPDATE**

I think this does what you want:

```
# Example data 4
df4 = pd.DataFrame({"val": [5, 3, 4, 2, 7], "signal": [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]})

df['target'] = np.minimum.accumulate((df.val + 3).where(df.signal.astype(bool), np.inf))
df['hit'] = df.val >= df.target
print(df)
```

Output in example 4:

```
   val  signal  target    hit
0    5       0     inf  False
1    3       1     6.0  False
2    4       1     6.0  False
3    2       1     5.0  False
4    7       0     5.0   True
```

Comment: I really like this approach, but I tried to apply your *updated* logic on Example 1 and it does not return my expected output (the target column is all NaN and naturally all hits are false)

Comment: Ah yes, you are right.  The `max` function won't work if there are any `np.nan` in the sequence. You could try using `where(df.signal.astype(bool), -1)` or something like that (as long as all `df.val` are greater than -1).

Comment: Can you please explain why there is a `NaN` in the 5th row of the target column in your example 1 desired output? Surely that row should also be a 'hit' also based on your condition `df.val >= df.target`.

Comment: since the target has been hit, and there is no signal to generate a new target, that row should have no target, aka NaN

Comment: Oh okay, that wasn't explained in the question.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I was hoping it would be clear by the fact that each target can only have one hit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is the logic you want to implement:

```
def transition(value, signal, prev_target, prev_hit):
    """Calculate target and hit in current time step"""
    if prev_hit:
        prev_target = np.nan
    if signal == 1:
        new_target = value + 3
        target = new_target if np.isnan(prev_target) else min(prev_target, new_target)
    else:
        target = prev_target
    hit = True if value >= target else False
    return target, hit
```

(PLEASE CONFIRM)

This works on the examples you provided so far (ignoring some values which I think are errors in your examples).

For example:

```
# Example data 3
df = pd.DataFrame({"val": [1, 4, 3, 4, 7], "signal": [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]})

# Prepare empty columns
df['target'] = None
df['hit'] = False
# Initial assumptions
target, hit = (np.nan, False)
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    target, hit = transition(row.val, row.signal, target, hit)
    df.loc[i, ['target', 'hit']] = target, hit
print(df)
```

Produces:

```
   val  signal target    hit
0    1       1      4  False
1    4       0      4   True
2    3       0    NaN  False
3    4       1      7  False
4    7       0      7   True
```

However, I think this requires a recursive solution due to the fact that a signal 'expires' after a hit.  If I'm right, then I don't think this is vectorizable.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, @Bill. I updated my question with a loopy version of the algorithm so you can see exactly what it is that I'm trying to do. I also corrected a mistake in the 4th example. I am afraid that this is non-vectorizable, but I'm still hoping for one of those lightbulb moments that you sometimes see on SO. Either way, thank you for your time :)